# Wireshark playback for regression testing

Tags: windows, gratis, networking, software-testing

I have captured traffic of our application using Wireshark, so I have a PCap file now. I'd like to use this capture file to do a regression test of our software, i.e. I'd like to

- perform a playback of the recorded HTTP requests (GET and POST)
- at the recorded speed or faster (e.g. at 200%, with the option to wait for a response to a previous request)
- compare the responses against the responses in the PCap file
- compare the response times against the response times in the PCap file (there should be a configurable threshold)
- exchange the target IP address of the PCap by a newer IP address if needed (e.g. for DHCP or when we configure a new machine)

The software

- should be gratis
- must work on Windows (7 SP1 x64 at least)
- may be a command line tool, but must be documented in that case and provide output in a documented and well-known format (e.g. XML, CSV)
- may also have a GUI
- must support at least HTTP with proprietary content (e.g. custom headers in the request, proprietary data in POST)