# Looking for windows tool to edit and resend packet

Tags: windows-7, wireless, packet-capture

I capture packet that I sent with wireshark.

I looking for windows tool to edit this packet and resend it

Comment: Scapy (http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#windows) is a useful tool to create and modify packets.

Comment: I doubt it exists: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27233/wireshark-playback-for-regression-testing

Answer (score 0):

If you can write cpp code I'd suggest using [PcapPlusPlus](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus)

Comment: I don't see how this satisfies the question. It ask for a tool, but this is a programming library.